# Using memcpy to copy a range of elements from an 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

Say we have two 2d arrays:

```
double matrix [64][100];
double array[64][32];
```

And we want to copy 32 elements from matrix[64][50:82] to array[64][32] using memcpy.
Do you the solution?

Comment: `matrix[64][50:82]` -- What is `50:82`?  That is not C++.

Comment: `matrix[64][...]` is out of bounds. Show your attempt to use `memcpy`.

Comment: So you want to copy elements from indexes 50..81 from each row of `matrix` to elements at indexes 0..31 of the the corresponding row of `array`?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy matrix [64][50:81] to array [64][32].

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to copy elements from indexes 50..81 from each row of matrix to elements at indexes 0..31 of the the corresponding row of array.

Comment: I'm afraid you should first read some tutorial/book on pointer arithmetic and how 2D arrays correspond to 1D arrays and then at least try to provide your attempt towards the solution.

Comment: Also, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
double matrix[64][100];
double array[64][32];

for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    memcpy(&array[i][0], &matrix[i][50], sizeof(double) * 32);
}
```

However, consider using [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead.  They will use `memcpy()` internally when safe to do so:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

double matrix[64][100];
double array[64][32];

for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    std::copy(&matrix[i][50], &matrix[i][82], &array[i][0]);
    or
    std::copy_n(&matrix[i][50], 32, &array[i][0]);
}
```